# Multiple Selection of ListTile

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter here i'm trying to select all the square boxes, given below is the code for single selection of ListTile when one tile is selected it changes it's background color to redAccent, but i need code for multiple selection where i can select all three ListTile or either two ListTile and not only one

```
class MultiSelect extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: GradientAppBar(
        title: Text('MultiSelect'),
      ),
      body: MultipleSelectItems(),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class MultipleSelectItems extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MultipleSelectItemsState createState() => _MultipleSelectItemsState();
}

class _MultipleSelectItemsState extends State<MultipleSelectItems> {
  String selected = "First";
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: GestureDetector(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 40,
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  selected = "First";
                });
              },
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
                height:100,
                width: double.maxFinite,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: selected == 'First' ? Colors.redAccent : Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                ),
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    'First',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontFamily: 'WorksSansSemiBold',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20)),
             GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  selected = "Second";
                });
              },
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
                height:100,
                width: double.maxFinite,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: selected == 'Second' ? Colors.redAccent : Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                ),
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    'Second',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontFamily: 'WorksSansSemiBold',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20)),
             GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  selected = "Third";
                });
              },
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
                height:100,
                width: double.maxFinite,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: selected == 'Third' ? Colors.redAccent : Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                ),
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    'Third',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontFamily: 'WorksSansSemiBold',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
              
            SizedBox(
              height: 40,
            ),
            MaterialButton(
              child: Text("Submit"),
              color: Colors.blueGrey,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: why not use CheckboxListTile, take a look here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CheckboxListTile-class.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am taking the requirement as you don't want to toggle, but to select multiple items. This is the solution.

In Flutter, creating a different `StatefulWidget` for the buttons, will be unique for every button, and when you select the buttons. And hitting each button will have unique informations only. I know it is little confusing but follow this, and you will understand.

```
class MultipleSelectItems extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MultipleSelectItemsState createState() => _MultipleSelectItemsState();
}

class _MultipleSelectItemsState extends State<MultipleSelectItems> {
  
  // This is responsible to crate your buttons 
  // Every button is created will be having it's unique instance only
  // Means, if you hit one button, it won't effect another, and you can select
  // multiple
  // And you don't have to declare your buttons multiple times in the code
  // Which is indeed bad way of coding :)
  List<Widget> get listTileWidgets{
     List<Widget> _widget = [SizedBox(height: 40.0)];
     List<String> _buttonName = ['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth'];
     
     // ListTileWidget is defined below in another StatefulWidget
     _buttonName.forEach((name){
         _widget.add(ListTileWidget(name: name));
         _widget.add(SizedBox(height: 20.0));
     });

     return _widget;
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Material(
       child: Container(
          child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: this.listTileWidgets
          )
       )
     );
  }
}


// This will accept name of the button which will be used to be given
// plus maintaining the uniqueness
class ListTileWidget extends StatefulWidget{
    final String name;

    ListTileWidget({Key key, this.name}):super(key:key);
    
    @override
    ListTileWidgetState createState() => ListTileWidgetState();
}

class ListTileWidgetState extends State<ListTileWidget>{
    bool isTapped = false;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context){
        return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
               setState(() => isTapped = true);
            },
            child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
                height:100,
                color: isTapped ? Colors.redAccent : Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                width: double.maxFinite,
                child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                        widget.name,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontFamily: 'WorksSansSemiBold',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Result you will get is below:

[image: Result]

I am sorry that, I have not added your "Submit" button. So in order to make that thing visible in your code, simply add this in your `Column` only, and you will be good to go:

```
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
  children: <Widget>[
     this.listTileWidgets,
     SizedBox(height: 40),
     MaterialButton(
       child: Text("Submit"),
       color: Colors.blueGrey,
       textColor: Colors.white,
       onPressed: () {},
     )
  ]
)
```

That's pretty much it now.

Comment: Thank you Sir  and how do I mark this pls guide me.

Comment: You're most welcome @AdamSilver. You can find a **tick mark** on the **top-left side of my answer**. You need to click on that, **it will turn green**. Also, you can upvote the answer, by clicking on the **up triangular box above 0** on this answer. You need to press, and it will increment the value to 1. This way we upvote and mark the answer correct :) Hope that helps

Comment: Sir till now i have created simple pages to learn flutter, watching videos from you tube but i need a course to learn all the flutter widget functions.

Comment: Hey @AdamSilver , I totally understand how difficult it is to find a better courses for learning something new. The best way to learn is to make a project on the particular `framework`, and that is how I learnt. **And did not follow any courses specifically.** Strategy would be, **1. Make Project 2. Follow StackOverFlow for help 3. Youtube Videos for understanding a particular thing**. Flutter has some websites too, [flutter dev](https://flutter.dev/) and [Official Flutter Youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwXdFgeE9KYzlDdR7TG9cMw)

Comment: Hey @AdamSilver also, we can **mark the single answer as correct out of multiple answers [if multiple extsts]**. You have marked the other answer, now **my answer is not marked anymore**. ALSO - **Marked means this is best solution to your problem which you found here, which means people will prefer that answer for the problem like yours, when they come visit your question**. It is okay that you feel like the other answer is more justifiable. But just wanted to tell you about it, since this is a new platform for you. That was indeed funny though. Hahaha!

Answer (score 0):

I've got your answer. Changing the string variable to be an array can complete what you are looking to do. Then by checking if "First" or "Second" or "Third" is in the array we can determine what color the ListTile should be. Also when the ListTile is tapped we need to check if the array contains that string to determine if we are going to remove the string from the array (aka turning the color to blue) or if we need to add the string to the array (aka turning the color to red). Below I have included all of those changes to your class. Hope this answer helps! Comment if you have any questions

```
class MultipleSelectItems extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MultipleSelectItemsState createState() => _MultipleSelectItemsState();
}

class _MultipleSelectItemsState extends State<MultipleSelectItems> {
  var theSelected = ["First"];
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Container(
        child: GestureDetector(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: 40,
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if(theSelected.contains("First")) {
                      theSelected.remove("First");
                    }
                    else {
                      theSelected.add("First");
                    }
                  });
                },
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
                  height: 100,
                  width: double.maxFinite,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: theSelected.contains('First') ? Colors.redAccent : Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                  ),
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      'First',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontFamily: 'WorksSansSemiBold',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20)),
               GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if(theSelected.contains("Second")) {
                      theSelected.remove("Second");
                    }
                    else {
                      theSelected.add("Second");
                    }
                  });
                },
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
                  height:100,
                  width: double.maxFinite,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: theSelected.contains('Second') ? Colors.redAccent : Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                  ),
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      'Second',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontFamily: 'WorksSansSemiBold',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20)),
               GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if(theSelected.contains("Third")) {
                      theSelected.remove("Third");
                    }
                    else {
                      theSelected.add("Third");
                    }
                  });
                },
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
                  height:100,
                  width: double.maxFinite,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: theSelected.contains("Third") ? Colors.redAccent : Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                  ),
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      'Third',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontFamily: 'WorksSansSemiBold',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
                
              SizedBox(
                height: 40,
              ),
              MaterialButton(
                child: Text("Submit"),
                color: Colors.blueGrey,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```